# Multiple project output types: compiling as an EXE and a LIB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, project-properties

I have a C++ project that builds as an EXE. However I also need to build the project as a static library (.LIB file). Right now in order to get a complete build, I need to build it in one format, then open the project properties and under General > Project Defaults > Configuration Type select the other format, accept, and recompile. It's a real hassle. Is there some way of specifying both types? I haven't seen anything on MSDN on this.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common (and particularly sane) way to solve your problem is to have a solution containing two projects. The first project should be a library (statically or dynamically linked, it doesn't matter) that contains most of your code. The second project should be an executable that references the library you've created in your first project.

Do it this way and a single build of your solution will produce both the executable and the library.

Comment: I would love to be able to break most of the code out into a separate project. That was what I wanted when this thing was being specified. Unfortunately the requirements I have preclude this. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Create two projects, add the same set of source files to both.

Comment: Duplicating the number of files makes no sense; you'll need to double the effort each time you make a change to the source.

Comment: @pmcs: Why? I'm not saying make a copy of every file and add the original to one project and a copy to another - I'm saying add the same file to both projects. Any change would show up in both projects, since it's the same physical file.

Comment: Suppose you have a few hundred header and source files, split across lots of directories. For an actively developed project the directory structure probably won't be stable, let alone the individual files themselves. Each time you modify the directory structure in the library project you'll have to manually update the executable project.
Much better simply to have a library project and an executable that references the library within the same solution. This is utterly standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old thread, but for the posterity: in case your project have a minimalist main.cpp, you could build a library from the whole .obj generated by the build, except main.obj.
A typical way would be to add this build on a pre-link event:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
[...]
  <PreLinkEvent>
    <Command>@ECHO ON
    "lib.exe" /NOLOGO /OUT:"$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).lib" "$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.obj"
    "lib.exe" /NOLOGO "$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).lib" /REMOVE:"$(IntermediateOutputPath)main.obj"</Command>
  </PreLinkEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

It was working with Visual Studio 2010 & 2019 (didn't test with the intermediates ones).