# Trying to build my single Visual Studio 2010 C++ project as both exe & DLL instead of creating new project again

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project:

I want to create both .exe & DLL for the same project. I'm okay with two compilation process but don't want to duplicate the project files. Because it leads to creating two different projects with two build configuration.

Anyone knows about this?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple project output types: compiling as an EXE and a LIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758022/multiple-project-output-types-compiling-as-an-exe-and-a-lib)

Comment: Nope, you need two projects.

Comment: @mat: Incorrect. A project can (in fact usually does) contain multiple configurations. There's nothing that prevents a project from containing configurations that generate different artifacts (like an EXE and a DLL).

Comment: @IInspectable may you suggest an example?

Comment: @ale Not sure what sort of example you are looking for. You'll find one in any default-generated Visual Studio project. Just open the .vcxproj file and search for `Condition=`. That allows you to customize virtually any build step based on conditions, such as the active configuration.

Comment: @IInspectable ok, I have understood.